Swift / MacOS - AVAudioEngineConfigurationChangeNotification sometimes not getting triggered after changing input\output devices
I want to use AVAudioEngine to mix multiple sound inputs including microphone input into files. But after any device change occurs sometimes AVAudioEngineConfigurationChangeNotification will not trigger and the engine will stop working.
I have a tap on the AVAudioEngine input node which stops working if the default input or the output device is changed. I fix that by starting the engine and reconnecting nodes after receiving AVAudioEngineConfigurationChangeNotification but sometimes it doesn't trigger and the tap stops working without any visible change on the engine. AVAudioEngine.isRunning still returns true in this broken state. Could the issue be with this notification as in:
Quote from apple's documentation:

When the audio engine’s I/O unit observes a change to the audio input or output hardware’s channel count or sample rate

So the notification shouldn't trigger if both devices are using the same format? Does the quote imply that if no format change happens then the engine should seamlessly switch devices?
I did try to connect sink node and just print out what it receives and it also breaks.
Basically any device change (input or output doesn't matter) interrupts the engine. But not all changes will trigger a notification even while breaking the engine.
Is there any fix to that?
Basic code snippet for AVEngine configuration:
audioEngine.inputNode
    .installTap(
        onBus: 0,
        bufferSize: 1024,
        format: audioEngine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
     ) { buffer, _ in
         do {
             let sampleBuffer = try buffer.convertToCMSampleBuffer()
         
             self.didOutputSampleBuffer.send((self.id, sampleBuffer))
         } catch {
             print(error)
         }
     }

let notification = NSNotification.Name.AVAudioEngineConfigurationChange

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self,
      selector: #selector(onInputChanged)
      name: notification,
      object: nil
)

audioEngine.prepare()

audioEngine.start()

Block for device change:

//Recreated tap in case format changed

audioEngine.start()

